# ERROR: Could not load Sales Channels for Stock in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

When I load my home page then shows that type of error .
[image]

so Please suggest me what i do for this error ,how i solve this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently upgraded to Magento 2.4.2 check that all modules are enabled using this command :

```
bin/magento module:status
```

You will see a list of enabled and disabled modules. It is possible some of the new inventory modules are disabled. You can enable these with the `module:enable` command or by editing the `app/etc/config.php` file and changing the status of disabled modules (0) to 1.

Remember to run `setup:upgrade` after making any changes to config.php.

Comment: All modules for inventory are enabled but that error persist.

Comment: Make sure you have flushed all caches and restarted your redis service, then try and run setup:upgrade again.